# LEFT JOIN in MySQL does not work right

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have trouble getting a right result with * LEFT JOIN.

I have 2 tables

`crist  |  id  |  tex`

and

`izteg  |  id  |  crist_id  |  ip`

I want to replace `tex` from the first table by taking it from the second table using `crist_id`

I tried the following, but something is not working:

```
$connect = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);
$sql = "SELECT id,tex FROM izteg  LEFT JOIN izteg ON izteg.id = crist.crist_id";
$zaqvka = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
{

    echo "sad";
    echo $row['tex'];
    echo $row['crist_id']; 
}
```

I may be missing something obvious

Comment: you're using two times the same table (izteg) where do you use crist?

Comment: What do you want to get from crist, and what do you want to get from izteg?

Comment: Crips, talk about confused!

Comment: changed everything to me and said no, code breaks the query exactly ... *SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this:  join with the `crist table` not to the same and also  `crist` table do not have  `crist_id` so how can you join on that.

```
SELECT crist_id,tex FROM izteg  LEFT JOIN crist ON izteg.crist_id = crist.id;
```

use this:`$zaqvka in while not $qry`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($zaqvka))
{
echo "sad";
echo $row['tex'];
echo $row['crist_id'];
}
```

Comment: Nothing comes, the code stops the query exactly.

Comment: @user3526544 just try the sql running in phpmyadmin i have corrected it.

Comment: see the updated sql.

Comment: nothing there, the explanations will again. Want from the second table field crist_id to earn the first tex

Comment: which table id do you want to show up.

Comment: crist_id the second = id of the first, therefore I can extract tex from the first

Comment: the above sql will give the crist_id and tex where ever izteg.crist_id = crist.id.

Comment: yes, but the code is broken. Just the application stops working.

Comment: yes your variable in while is wrong see the updated answer.

Comment: for development you should set error reporting on.

Comment: ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); put these on top of your php file and see what error you are getting.

Comment: I brought it to work like this:
$zaqvka = mysql_query("SELECT crist_id,tex FROM izteg  LEFT JOIN crist ON izteg.crist_id = crist.id");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($zaqvka))

{
echo $row['tex'];

echo $row['crist_id'];
}

but how to get him to show them my latest first which are izteg?

Comment: glad you got the result.if you feel this helped you then mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't use the first table in the query. The solution is above.

```js
$connect = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);

$zaqvka = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT id,tex FROM crist  LEFT JOIN izteg ON izteg.id = crist.crist_id") or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
{
echo "sad";
echo $row['tex'];
echo $row['crist_id'];
}
```

Comment: your sql will say ambiguous for id because it is vailable in both table  use tablename.id instead.